# How to change default start page of Glassfish?

Tags: redirect, glassfish

Currently when I type in the URL of my webapp, say "http://abc.edu/mywebapp/", I am taken to the login page of my webapp. When I type "http://abc.edu/", I am taken to the GlassFish info page. How can I do it such that when I key in "http://abc.edu/", I will be taken to my login page and not the GlassFish info page?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can set one of your webapps as default. This can be done with the admin console:

*Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> server*

Then select your default web application from the drop-down menu. If your webserver port is 8080, you can start your application now by:

`http://hostname:8080`

instead of `http://hostname:8080/webapp`

Notice that "server" is the name of Glassfish's default virtual server. If you configured a different virtual server for your webapp you need to change it accordingly.

Furthermore regarding [this source](http://www.lubby.org/result.jsf?DB=lkb_linux_english&ID=251), there might be some problems with JDBCRealms.

**Option 2:** You could also deploy your default webapp to "/" instead of "/webapp" but I think the first option is more flexible.

Comment: The drop-down menu mentioned is next to the label *Default Web Module:*

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your context root to "/" Edit the `application.xml` that is where the context root for the app is set. You might have to undeploy the default context root inorder to do that (that is what I do in JBoss, I undeploy ROOT.war).

Comment: application.xml is not usually part of a web app.

Comment: I did edit `<application context-root="/" ... >` in domain.xml and it works