# Glassfish Application URL

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I've just installed `Glassfish` Web Profile (**Open source edition**) on my VPS. I have deployed my application successfully on domain1. Now the application is accessible on `http://localhost/myapplication`

How can I config the server in a way my app will be accessible on address: `http://localhost`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from [my own answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287577/how-to-change-default-start-page-of-glassfish/6288905#6288905):

**Option 1:** You can set one of your webapps as default. This can be done with the admin console:

Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> server

Then select your default web application from the drop-down menu. If your webserver port is 8080, you can start your application now by:

http://hostname:8080

instead of http://hostname:8080/webapp

Notice that "server" is the name of Glassfish's default virtual server. If you configured a different virtual server for your webapp you need to change it accordingly.

Furthermore regarding [this source](http://www.lubby.org/result.jsf?DB=lkb_linux_english&ID=251), there might be some problems with JDBCRealms.

**Option 2:** You could also deploy your default webapp to "/" instead of "/webapp" but I think the first option is more flexible.